# All routes except the index route showing an Error 404 while developing on the Express Application Generator

Tags: javascript, express, model-view-controller, routes

I am building a day planner, and while I was setting the routes I noticed I am receiving a 404 for every routes other than the main Home page route ie, index or "/".

This is app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var calendarRouter = require('./routes/calendar');

var app = express();

//Set up mongoose connection
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb+srv://<user-name>:<password>@cluster0.3xw67.gcp.mongodb.net/<db-name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/calendar', calendarRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is the calendar.js route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var schedule_controller = require('../controllers/scheduleController');

router.get('/', schedule_controller.index);

router.get('/calendar/create', schedule_controller.schedule_create_get);

router.post('/calendar/create', schedule_controller.schedule_create_post);

router.get('/calendar/:id/delete', schedule_controller.schedule_delete_get);

router.post('/calendar/:id/delete', schedule_controller.schedule_delete_post);

router.get('/calendar/:id/update', schedule_controller.schedule_update_get);

router.post('/calendar/:id/update', schedule_controller.schedule_update_post);

router.get('/calendar/event/:id', schedule_controller.schedule_details); 

router.get('/events', schedule_controller.schedule_list);

module.exports = router;
```

This is the index.js route, I did a redirect here!

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/calendar');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the Controller for the calendar.js route.

```
var Schedule = require('../models/schedule');

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Site Home Page');
};

exports.schedule_list = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule List');
};

exports.schedule_details = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule Detail: ' + req.params.id);
};

exports.schedule_create_get = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule create GET');
};

exports.schedule_create_post = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule create POST');
};

exports.schedule_delete_get = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule delete GET');
};

exports.schedule_delete_post = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule delete POST');
};

exports.schedule_update_get = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule update GET');
};

exports.schedule_update_post = function(req, res) {
    res.send('NOT IMPLEMENTED: Schedule update POST');
};
```

Comment: **NOTE** I am using the [Tutorial on MDN for Local Library Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Tutorial_local_library_website) as a reference/ guide to this application.

Comment: I just found out that if I interchange the routes it works fine. Routing of index is the only route that works.
I think it has something to do with redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the bug it was me using index url that is `/` which I redirected to `/calendar`. And I have been using the rest of the url routes without calling the redirected one ie, `/calendar`.

I tried calling the routes with `/calendar/calendar` and it works!

I don't yet know clearly how to explain this. I hope fellow stackoverflow'ers could explain why this is happening.

Here's me trying a noob explanation!

Redirecting index route `/` to another url route, changes the main url route of the website(address). So all the sub routes which is **everything other than** the index route should explicitly call the redirected route (new address). Because every-time we call the old address the redirection changes it to the new one. Making the old address a dead one.

(**Humour :** I would like to point out an example considering numbers. It's like whole numbers and natural numbers. Redirection is when the whole number changes to natural number.)